# Unlock orientation when viewing picture fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, orientation

My `UITableViewCell` has a `UIImageView` in it. When the users taps on the `UIImageView`, an `[IDMPhotoBrowser]`(https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser) is presented from the `UIImageView`. The app is portrait only, however, when viewing the photo fullscreen in IDMPhotoBrowser, I'd like to give the user the ability to rotate to any orientation.

The `IDMPhotoBrowser` is presented on the `UITableViewCell's delegate`. The delegate is a regular `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. The delegate is also a contained in a `UINavigationController` which is contained in a `UITabBarController`. I have tried many different solutions involving extending `IDMPhotoBrowser` and trying to add functions that add support for all orientations, I have tried presenting the `IDMPhotoBrowser` on the `UITabBarController`, the `UINavigationController` and `the delegate UIViewController`. I have also tried flipping a boolean located in the `UITabBarController` subclass that is then referenced in the function that asks for supported orientations, such that the supported orientations changes in relation to when the app presents the `IDMPhotoBrowser`. Nothing has worked.

The whole app needs to be constrained to only portrait orientation except for when the user is viewing an `IDMPhotoBrowser` or an `AVPlayerViewController` in fullscreen.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a UINavigationController parent class, inside your UINavigationController(parent) override these methods this way:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
}
```

in your VC you want to be rotated:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .All
}
```

in your VC you want NOT to be rotated:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .AllButUpsideDown
}
```

Then push (or set as root VC etc) your Browser or Browser's parent VC in this navigation controller.

Comment: The `ViewController` needs to support UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All only when the user is viewing the IDMPhotoBrowser. How does this code achieve that? This code simply supports all orientations all the time.

Comment: Edited the answer, go on with a navigation controller and push ViewController in that navigationcontroller.

Comment: So you're saying to have the `UINavigationController` subclass support all interface orientations, then have the `ViewController` support only portrait, then push the `IDMPhotoBrowser` and have it support all interface orientations? I think that would work as a UIViewController intersects its supported interface orientations with its UINavigationController, however, the IDMPhotoBrowser is presented, not pushed. So because the `ViewController`, which supports only portrait, would be presenting the IDMPhotoBrowser, wouldn't the IDMPhotoBrowser simply inherit supporting only portrait from the VC?

Comment: Also I have tried wrapping the IDMPhotoBrowser inside of a UINavigationController then presenting the UINavigationController and that solved the entire orientation problem however the animation where the UIImageView animates from the UITableViewCell to the fullscreen viewer was ruined.

Comment: You can also do it as in navigationController:
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
      return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
 }

and in your VC sometimes you can have all sometimes you can have only portrait etc.

Comment: I am facing an issue when the `Done` button at the right top corner of the screen is touched, the image the full screen in not dismissed. It's like there is certain single pixel point I have to tap in order to get the view dismissed. Any idea how to fix this?